# OneToMany updating/deleting items

Tags: hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have this entity graph:

```
public class ApplicationUser {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "applicationuser_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "applicationuser_seq", sequenceName = "applicationuser_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "applicationUser", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Set<Facility> facilities;
}

public class Facility {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "facility_seq")
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "facility_seq", sequenceName = "facility_seq", allocationSize = 1)
    private long id;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "applicationuser")
    private ApplicationUser applicationUser;
}
```

So an `ApplicationUser` has one to many `Facility` records.
Now i want to update/delete the `Facility` records.

Let´s say user bob has two facilities: fac1, fac2.
After the update/delete user bob should have fac2, fac4.

So my service looks like this:

```
ApplicationUser bob = applicationUserRepository.findsById(id);
bob.modify("fac2", "fac4");
applicationUserRepository.save(bob)
```

modify helper (inside `ApplicationUser` type):

```
void modify(List<String> facilities) {
        this.facilities = new HashSet<>();
        this.facilities.addAll(Facility.of(facilities, this));
}
```

My hibernate log says the following:

1. select u from user u where u.id = 123
2. select nextval ('facility_seq')
3. select nextval ('facility_seq')
4. insert into Facility
5. insert into Facility

At Step 5 there is an error, because `Facility` fac2 is already there and has a unique key (combined with applicationuser) on it.

So my questions is?
Why are there no `delete` statements issued?
I have cleared the `private Set<Facility> facilities;` and by `cascade = CascadeType.ALL` i would have assumed that the cleared items will be deleted as well?
Instead of manually updating all items of `Facility` i would like to delete all items, and then rebuild it newly by the updated items.

Answer (score 1):

That won't work unfortunately since AFAIK by using `mappedBy` you are essentially telling Hibernate that the other side of the relationship should be used for managing the association. I think the following should work though:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name = "applicationuser")
private Set<Facility> facilities;
```